# How to restrict automatic build trigger after the organization scan in Jenkins?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have organization created on the Jenkins server. Inside its configuration I have specified my GitHub organization URL. And Inside my GitHub organization there exists repository containing Jenkinsfile.

Whenever I scanned the organization on the Jenkins, if the scan finds any updations to the Jenkinsfile inside any repository or new repository containing Jenkinsfile on the GitHub then pipeline is triggered i.e stages inside the Jenkinsfile get executed.

How to restrict this automatic build trigger after the organization scan?

Answer (score 2):

1. We can restrict this automatic build trigger after the organization scan. Update the organization configuration on Jenkins to alter the field name *Branch names to build automatically* to **empty** .

   please refer below image.

   [image]
2. We can specify the branch name for which we want to trigger the pipeline in the above field name *Branch names to build automatically* .

Answer (score 0):

This feature mentioned by *kalyani chaudhari* was removed from [Branch API plugin](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47859) the actual way is using the Named branch and set a regular expression which will be ignored.